# How to find the first day of any ChronoUnit including quarters in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

What I am trying to achieve is a simple method which would use a ChronoUnit + duration to return the first day of the following ChronoUnit.

Context:

```
ChronoUnit unit = ChronoUnit.MONTHS(WEEKS, QUARTERS, YEARS, DAYS); // Supplied by an enum instance
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("1990-12-15",df);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("1991-06-07",df);
LocalDate lastCompoundDate = end;
LocalDate current = start;
ArrayList compoundingDates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();

while (current.isBefore(end)) {
    compoundingDates.add(current);
    current = findFirstDateOf(current.plus(duration, unit), unit);
    
}

compoundingDates.add(end)

return CompoundingDates
```

Not sure what my best bet for the implementation is, I googled and it seems like getting a a first day of week and month might be trivial with standard java classes, but quarters are a bit tricker. I found people suggesting this: https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/ as well, but don't know if that's a way to go since it doesn't provide a clear interface I am looking for.

In a nutshell, I just want to avoid doing all the `if-elif-elif` depending on the type of chrono unit and wonder if there is a clean, simple way to express that in java. If it's impossible at least maybe there is a clean way to do it for everything, but quarters?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem that would require me if-elseing distinguishing between chronounits rather than being agnostic to which one is passed. But I agree, that method would work for the quarter use case.

Comment: But Quarters aren't a [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) anyway

Comment: You could make your own enum that has the units that you want to support, along with a lambda in the enum that  references the different methods you'll need.  The enum itself will be a bit hairy, but the use of it will be very clean.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am doing. I am implementing the enum, but want it to be pretty and was wondering if there is a well-defined java pattern for something like that.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear from your question that you were creating your own enum instead of using the JDK `ChronoUnit` enum.  As I said, the pattern is that the enum has a field which is a method reference.  I guess its type would be `Function<LocalDate,LocalDate>` in your case.  Then you'd assign a different lambda for each element of your enum.  That way, all the code for finding the "start of" a unit is wrapped up in the enum itself.

Comment: Just a tip - don't call your enum `ChronoUnit`, because it will create confusion down the track with the JDK `ChronoUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `firstMonthOfQuarter` method of the `Month` enum to help you adjust a `LocalDate` to the beginning of the quarter.  A solution using this could look something like this.

```
public static LocalDate startOfQuarter(LocalDate arg) {
    Month firstMonthOfQuarter = arg.getMonth().firstMonthOfQuarter();
    return arg.withDayOfMonth(1).withMonth(firstMonthOfQuarter.getValue());
}
```